# Implement a slide-sidebar like Tinder.app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, ecslidingviewcontroller

Does anyone can open [Tinder.app](http://www.tinder.com/)?
Well, the app implements a simple-but-slick animation effect when the user taps on the top-left menu icon button. The focal points of this animation are:

- Status bar fades out/in based on when the left menu sidebar is opening or closing;
- When the left menu sidebar is opened there's a little bounce effect of the main view controller just slide to right;
- When the left menu is opened, if you try to close it  you can see there's a little bounce of the main view controller that shows the *right* sidebar (the "All Matches" view controller).

I've just cloned [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) repo and played a little with it but unfortunately it seems that (out-of-the-box) it have only classic animations and not those bounce animations I said before I'm trying to achieve.

Does anyone knows how to implement something like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many ways to do this, you can wirte your own code to do this. But there are many free work available, which may helpful. And you will not try to reinvent the wheel.

1. [IIViewDeckController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/iiviewdeckcontroller)
2. [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)
3. [JTRevealSlidebar](https://github.com/jamztang/JTRevealSidebarDemo)
4. [SASlideMenu](https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu)
5. [JA Slide Panel](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels)
6. [BenHall](https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation)
7. [SlideNavigationController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/slidenavigationcontroller)

There are plenty more available, but above mentioned are easy to use and having demo project also.